# Constant time string reversal with smart strings?

Tags: c, string, reverse

In C, instead of keeping track of only the length of the string, what if we keep track of its direction as well? For example, if `str = "hello"` was laid out in memory (as given by malloc), we would say it has a positive direction (+1) and therefore pass +1 into function arguments. Instead of taking O(n) to reverse this string, we can now just say `rev = str[size - 1]` with direction -1 and it is therefore treated differently. I realize the null termination might bring up some issues but given that we have the string length and the starting character in memory we do not need to care about the null termination (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is this a viable option if string reversal is critical in a program? Can someone give me a reason why I should not do this? Has anyone heard or seen this?

Sorry if my formatting is off, this is one of my first time posting. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any library function would probably iterate the string forward regardless of your direction flag though.

Comment: That's true. When using other conventions I'm sure it is not advised, but if building something from the ground up it could be an interesting foundation no?

Comment: It's possible to implement it but you'll have to do it yourself. This is a very rare need (reversed strings) so your solution (which would work) wouldn't be used very much outside your program.

Comment: As a genuine curiosity, what task *outside of academia* has string reversal as "critical in  a program".

Comment: I think only needed to reverse strings in production code maybe twice or three times in ~15 years. String reversal is an interview problem in my experience.

Comment: The only way to have the sting reversal done in `O(1)` is to store it in reverse direction as well.

Comment: I realize this probably wouldn't be used often I was just curious about the principle. I definitely cannot think of any examples, but it was just an interesting thought that occurred to me.

Comment: Another question is the purpose of such an operation. Because the accessing functions can be just modified in such a way that will be traversing the string in the opposite direction.

Comment: @WhozCraig String (or rather vector) rotate (essential for in-place merge) is most likely implemented as 3 reversals. Not that the direction flag would be of any help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that in order to reverse a string, you are going to have to copy the string in some way.  Outside of some sort of MMU trick where the system's memory reading is reversed at the addressing level, this necessitates having to traverese the string at least once.  Even if copying 4/8/16+ bytes at a time, this is still a linear operation.

Now, if you can just read the string in place, in reverse (using a special iterator or something), then perhaps you could consider this an O(1) operation, provided that this special iterator is also O(1).